# Что лучше сравнивать - даты или строки?

Tags: java

Нужно сравнивать данные по дате, но можно сравнивать по стрингу:

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
date = dateFormat.parse(dateTime.getDay() + "." + dateTime.getMonth() + "." + dateTime.getYear());
dateFromFile = dateFormat.parse(filename.split(".")[0]);
```

Их можно перевести и в стринг, и в дату, и оба сравнения будут правильными. Но какое сравнение будет работать быстрее?

Comment: Сравнение строк имеет вообще право быть неправильным. Например, лексикографическое сравнения даже чисел не айс:

    "10.01.01" > "2.01.01"

Если в вашем формате сначала пишется день, то всё вообще тухло:

    "31.01.01" > "11.01.99"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По дате, естественно! Дата, по сути, является оберткой для Long. И сравнение дат - не что иное, как сравнение LONG'ов. А сравнение даты через приведение ее к строке - это вообще извращение!

Comment: Сравнивать через дату - это правильно и красиво. Но нужно помнить, что преобразование строки в дату - это "тяжелая операция". Достаточно тяжелая. И если нужно отсортировать несколько сотен записей по дате, то лучше вначале преобразовать все даты, а потом сортировать. А если в компараторе делать каждый раз преобразование, то будет очень долго.

Comment: @KoVadim Думаю, правильно будет просто хранить даты в не в стоковом виде, а преобразовывать непосредственно при выводе на экран) И тогда проблем с сортировкой не будет!

Answer (score 0):

В юникстайм ещё можно переводить и сравнивать. Часто так и делаю.